# R barplots in a loop and save them to a file

Tags: r

I want to make multiple barplots by using a for loop, and save the plots as seperate .bmp files.

I start from a list of data frames (covpatient). I know how to make a single barplot, but I don't know how to put them in a for loop & save the results.

```
for (i in 1:length(covpatient)) {
       filename = paste(covpatient[[1]]$gene[1],"bmp", sep = ".")
       barplot ... OK
       print(?)
       dev.off()
}
```

Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
for (i in 1:length(covpatient)) {
       filename = paste(covpatient[[1]]$gene[1],"bmp", sep = ".")
       # You just missed this:
       bmp(filename)
       barplot ... OK
       dev.off()
}
```